# the relocation field in careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/ objectives changes the country of Georgia to the American state of Georgia

Tags: bug

The Objectives section of http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/cv/ asks the question 'Will you relocate?'  Entering a location of 'Tbilisi, Georgia' results in the Objectives listing 'Willing to relocate to Tbilisi, GA.'

GA is shorthand for the American state of Georgia, but not for the country of Georgia, i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(country)

While I might expect stackoverflow to have an American viewpoint, this error occurred at Careers UK: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/  Perhaps I should also add that I have met more Americans than British working in Tbilisi, so I feel this bug would be worthwhile fixing.

Comment: Attempting to enter just Tbilisi (without reference to Georgia) triggers a rewriting to Tbilisi, GA.

Comment: Attempting to enter თბილისი (instead of Tbilisi) triggers the clever, but wrong, guess of 'London, United Kingdom'.

Comment: Unicode is your friend ;-) http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Adding 'Sakartvelo' is intelligently transformed into 'Georgia' (and not GA).