# Do we need to reopen all bugs closed as site-specific and prevent further closing them on MSE?

Tags: discussion, support, bug-reports, site-specific

Based on the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389144/html-entities-on-the-button-in-create-tag-synonym-dialog?noredirect=1#comment1297692_389144) and the post itself [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250152/3240681) it seems that closing bugs as site-specific on MSE is not legitimate. Am I right?

If so, should we then reopen all closed as site-specific bug reports on MSE and prevent further closing of that type of questions?

Here is example of some old closed as site-specific bug reports:

- [Stack Overflow 'review' button is slow, and test questions are slower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229345/339911)
- [Downvoted but question stayed at zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334832/339911)
- [the relocation field in careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/ objectives changes the country of Georgia to the American state of Georgia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159699/339911)

You can find more by looking closely at [that list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D%20closed%3A1%20duplicate%3A0%20migrated%3A0) (closed, not duplicate and not migrated).

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but that comment says Child Meta - but I don't believe MSE is a child meta site

Comment: @cocomac good catch. But I don't see the reason to allow BR based on different child-metas, but forbid them on MSE.

Comment: The post about https://careers.stackoverflow.com is not a good example, as it was retired. The "Downvoted..." doesn't look like a good example either. The [tag:bug] tag should be removed b/c the OP was looking for help about why the Stack Overflow was behaving differently than expected; the answer explains that it was an experiment.

Comment: You missed the whole point of the close reason, which is unique to this site. Meta Stack Exchange. Anyone who telling you it's not legit to close as site specific is totally wrong, or another option you misunderstood what was said or written.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard I refer to the comment and post of other users, that not my point in base. I'm just asking how to react to it.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ not really. You clearly say closing as site specfic is not legit, and with this I strongly disagree.

Answer (score 8):

### No, not all, but it's likely that at least some should be reopened.

##### Valid bug reports should not be closed *just* because they only affect one site, but might be migrated (which is a type of closure).

A valid bug report should not be closed *just* because it only occurs on a single site which isn't the current site, as bugs should be able to be reported on any meta site. That includes not closing bug report questions on Meta Stack Exchange *only* because the bug affects only one site. This is consistent with the company's intent stated in "[Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250152/3773011)".

It is, however, reasonable for the moderators to *choose* to migrate a report about a bug which only occurs on a single site to the child meta site for that site, if that specific report could be better handled on the affected site. Migrating it may make it easier for the bug report to be seen by the users who are affected by the bug, make it easier to reproduce the bug on the site, and for potential workarounds to be discussed specific to that site. For migration, that criteria is somewhat different than the usual requirement that a question needs to be off-topic on the source site in order for it to be migrated. Overall, the goal should be to do what's best for the system as a whole, which may make it beneficial to migrate such bug reports, or not, but that's going to be a judgement call on a question by question basis.

##### We should not be reopening questions, if they should be closed for other reasons.

The general policy is that we don't reopen questions just to close them again for another reason. A moderator might do so for organizational reasons, but that's not something which regular users should be doing in most cases, because it's a *lot* of work for very little benefit, requiring coordination between up to a total of 10 reopen and close votes.

##### [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions should be reopened, if the *only* reason for closure is that the bug *is* affecting only one site.

There's quite a bit more to the issue of if the bug report question should be reopened than *just* because it was closed for being about one site. It's often the case that such questions should be closed for other reasons too. So...

If the bug is still valid (e.g., is, in fact, a bug (i.e., is currently reproducible) and hasn't been reported elsewhere; e.g., after closure here, the user may have reposted on the affected child meta, and we, generally, don't permit posting the same question on multiple sites), then, yes, the bug report question should be reopened.

### There's a lot of organizational work which could/should be done with both [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions.

There's a boatload of work that could and should be done to clean up both [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions.

On Meta Stack Exchange, there are, currently, 6,170 [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions which match the [search `is:q closed:no locked:no [bug] -[status-review] -[status-completed] -[status-bydesign] -[status-norepro] -[status-declined]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+locked%3Ano+%5Bbug%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D). Many of those probably should have some type of [status-foo](/questions/tagged/status-foo) tag added. Many others should probably be closed for a variety of reasons, including as "no repo"/"obsolete", due to "changes to the system ... have rendered it obsolete". Probably at least some of them aren't actually bug reports, so should be edited to remove the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

##### Let's first work on newer questions, rather than ones from a long time ago.

Overall, I feel the first priority should be on the [1,028 of such bug reports which were created on or after 2020-05-29](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+created%3A2020-05-29..+locked%3Ano+%5Bbug%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D), which was the date when [SE announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca) that they were changing to use the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to indicate which questions should be brought to staff attention. Prior to that change (presumably), SE staff was monitoring all meta sites for [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions. After that change, SE staff were relying on a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag being added to such questions to indicate that staff should be made aware of them. At some point, the monitoring of the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag stopped and such questions were no longer guaranteed to be seen by SE, unless a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag was added, which then automatically creates a ticket in SE's internal tracking system. The upshot is that the company is probably not even aware of a *large* portion of those 1000+ bug reports.

##### Don't just go flagging everything to have a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag added.

Now, it's *not* the case that every such question should get a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag, as [there *is* supposed to be some pre-filtering done prior to the tag being added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca). The questions should be evaluated and ones which are real, current, reproducible, and impactful issues should get a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag. It's also likely that a substantial portion of the questions should be handled in other ways, including being closed for whatever appropriate reason or an appropriate other [status-foo](/questions/tagged/status-foo) tag added. All of that's a lot of work, for both users and moderators, even if we limit it to the questions posted after 2020-05-29.

Comment: Disagree about bugs specific to one site. We don't need here bugs about the numerous SO-only features.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Your disagreement is expected. However, A) the above direction is consistent with the intent behind the company's expressed directive. If a MSE wants to close, by something other than migration, otherwise valid bug reports because the bug affects only one site, then explicit approval should be sought from the company. If they say it's fine for MSE to close such bug reports *only* because they affect one site, then OK. I would, however, suggest you consider that their response could very easily be that such bug reports are to remain open here on MSE and *not* be migrated.

Comment: B) I understand your desire for MSE to be "clean", but the best solution isn't to completely reject the bug report merely because it was posted here instead of a, potentially, more appropriate per-site meta. Doing it as described above allows both the bug report for a bug affecting a single site to be retained by the SE Network *and*, if the mods agree migration is appropriate in the specific case, for the bug report to be on the per-site meta for the affected site. If you want such a bug report off of MSE, then raise a mod flag asking for it to be migrated to the appropriate per-site meta.

Comment: So we agree to disagree. You think the "specific to one site" should be removed wholly, if not applied to **all** site specific questions it's worthless, and I disagree. However, neither of us can decide such a thing, so nothing will come out of it anyway.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard No, I didn't say that the "specific to one site" close reason should be removed wholly. I've said that it shouldn't be applied to bug reports, which is a limited subset of its use.

Comment: I know, but if not applied to all cases, it just becomes confusing and useless, hence should be removed.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard No, no it doesn't. That's a very pessimistic or dogmatic view. It's quite possible and reasonable to have a small portion of questions to which it doesn't apply (and to which it, arguably, should never have applied). It would be *just like it already is for bug report questions on any other meta site*.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have any examples of site-specific bugs posted here and closed? [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1751126) are all [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s closed as off-topic (there's no way in SEDE to check the specific off-topic reason, like site-specific). Some questions may be wrongly tagged, but the regulars (and staff) are keen to remove the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag when it doesn't apply.

Also note that we frequently migrate questions, including [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s, to Meta Stack Overflow, because they've been adequately answered there, or have a higher chance to be. The most recent example:
[Lost Silver Badges on Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388915/295232). Other examples were bugs related to functionality specific to Stack Overflow, like Documentation, Teams, Dark Mode and the Developer Survey.

Comment: e.g. [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229345/339911), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334832/339911), [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159699/339911)... can find more, but tedious

Comment: @αλεχολυτ only the first example might be considered "legit" here, I wouldn't close it today, but no point reopening it now. Other two are correctly closed and should stay closed. We don't need Careers bugs here, and the second example is about SO only experiment, nobody outside SO can possibly know, or should know, about it. It's something done on SO only, so the closing is perfect. That's exactly what per-site meta is for.